# Finding commutator of $\mathbb D_n$ and $\mathbb S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I have to find $[G,G]$ (the commutator of $G$) for the the dihedral group, $\mathbb D_n$ ; and the symmetric group, $\mathbb S_4$. What tools, theorems could I use in order to find these two commutators?. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: You have to find the (unique) minimal normal subgroup $N$ such that the quotient $G/N$ is abelian.